# 2048 in javascript: updating the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am in a computer science class at my high school, and for my final project, my partner and I have decided to make 2048. We are not going to have the tiles "move", but instead, the 4x4 board will have "tiles" that are have properties of the number and color of the "tile" as it appears on the board. We are able to get the x and y coordinates of a tile to change, but the canvas will not update. We have had this problem for two weeks now, and have tried everything, but nothing has worked. Our code is posted below.
Please keep in mind that as we have only used javascript for a couple months, and only to do very simple things, our understanding is limited. Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<title>2048</title>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="410" height="410" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<script>
var x = 10;
var y = 10;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode == 37)//left
    {
        x -= 100;
        console.log("x:"+ x);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 38)//up
    {
        y -= 100;
        console.log("y:"+ y);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 39)//right
    {
        x += 100;
        console.log("x:"+ x);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 40)//down
    {
        y += 100;
        console.log("y:"+ y);
    }
});
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// grey rectangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "2";
ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
ctx.rect(5, 5, 400, 400);
ctx.stroke();

// blue rectangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "5";
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.rect(x, y, 100, 100);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill();  
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to call the paint code again. consider adding a function. :)

Comment: Have you tried hitting F12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your game needs is a game loop. So the drawing needs to happen continously, at the moment you draw only one time at the beginning.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function draw() {
    // clear the canvas so the old rectangles are gone
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    // grey rectangle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
    ctx.rect(5, 5, 400, 400);
    ctx.stroke();

    // blue rectangle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "5";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.rect(x, y, 100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
}

// repeat game loop function forever, 30 times per second
window.setInterval(draw, 1000.0 / 30.0)
```

Notice the use of `window.setInterval` and `ctx.clearRect`.

Comment: This works too, probably better than my answer because you won't need to worry about when to call `draw`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you want to update what is shown on the canvas, you have to 'Draw' again.  Your code will run once when the page loads but never draws again so your changes to `x` and `y` are never seen.

I added a draw function here that is called on startup and after each keydown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
<title>2048</title>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="410" height="410" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<script> 
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var x = 10;
var y = 10;   

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode == 37)//left
    {
        x -= 100;
        console.log("x:"+ x);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 38)//up
    {
        y -= 100;
        console.log("y:"+ y);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 39)//right
    {
        x += 100;
        console.log("x:"+ x);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 40)//down
    {
        y += 100;
        console.log("y:"+ y);
    }
    draw();
});

function draw(){   
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); 
  // grey rectangle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "2";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "grey"; 
  ctx.rect(5, 5, 400, 400);
  ctx.stroke();

  // blue rectangle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx.rect(x, y, 100, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fill();  
}

draw();

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: c and ctx should be outside of the function