# making 2048 game: referencing object names

Tags: javascript, html, object, for-loop

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553052/2048-in-javascript-updating-the-canvas) I had a problem with my 2048 game that I am making in HTML and Javascript and I am having trouble again. This time, I am trying to make a for/in loop that can check to see if the squares to the left, right, top and bottom are filled. **What I need is a way to refer to the numbers of the squares while still being able to refer to the properties of the objects.** I am doing my best to explain what I am trying to do. I hope the comments in my code explain what each block does. Thank you for your help.

```js
/*
    
            Math.floor(Math.random()*(1-16+1)+1) <------
                                                       |
    this code picks a random number between 1 and 16___|
    switch ()
    */
//this function creates a method to create objects
function square(full, color, number) {
    this.full = full;
    this.color = color;
    this.number = number;
  }
  //this block creates objects for each square
var sq1 = new square(true, "black", 2);
var sq2 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq3 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq4 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq5 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq6 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq7 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq8 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq9 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq10 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq11 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq12 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq13 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq14 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq15 = new square(false, "grey", 2);
var sq16 = new square(false, "grey", 2);

//creates a board with the .full properties of the squares
board = [sq1.full, sq2.full, sq3.full, sq4.full, sq5.full, sq6.full, sq7.full, sq8.full, sq9.full, sq10.full, sq11.full, sq12.full, sq13.full, sq14.full, sq15.full, sq16.full];
//creates var sq_num to help check if items to left, up, right and down are full
var sq_num =

  //this giant code block conducts all movement
  function movement() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      /*for (sq_num in board)
      {
          if sq_num */


      if (event.keyCode == 37) //left
      {
        if (sq4.full == true) {

          sq4.color = sq1.color
          sq4.color = "grey"
          sq1.color = true
        }
        if (sq8.full == true) {
          sq8.color = sq7.color
          sq7.color = "black"
        }

        if (sq12.full == true) {
          sq12.color = sq11.color
          sq11.color = "black"
        }
        if (sq16.full == true) {
          sq16.color = sq15.color
          sq15.color = "black"
        }
      } else if (event.keyCode == 38) //up
      {
        sq13.color = sq9.color
        sq9.color = "black"

        sq14.color = sq10.color
        sq10.color = "black"

        sq15.color = sq11.color
        sq11.color = "black"

        sq16.color = sq12.color
        sq12.color = "black"
      } else if (event.keyCode == 39) //right
      {
        if (sq1.full == true) {
          sq1.color = sq2.color
          sq2.color = "black"
          sp2.full = true
        }
        if (sq2.full == true) {
          sq2.color = sq3.color
          sq3.color = "black"
          sq3.full = true
        }

        if (sq5.full == true) {
          sq5.color = sq6.color
          sq6.color = "black"

        }

        if (sq9.full == true) {
          sq9.color = sq10.color
          sq10.color = "black"
        }

        if (sq13.full = true) {
          sq13.color = sq14.color
          sq14.color = "black"
        }
      } else if (event.keyCode == 40) //down
      {
        sq1.color = sq5.color
        sq5.color = "black"

        sq2.color = sq6.color
        sq6.color = "black"

        sq3.color = sq7.color
        sq7.color = "black"

        sq4.color = sq8.color
        sq8.color = "black"
      }
    })
  };
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
//this function draws each square where it should be in the formation of a board.
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); // clear the canvas so the old rectangles are gone

  // board
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "2";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
  ctx.rect(5, 5, 610, 610);
  ctx.stroke();

  // sq1
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(10, 10, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq1.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq2
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(160, 10, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq2.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq3
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(310, 10, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq3.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq4
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(460, 10, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq4.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq5
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(10, 160, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq5.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq6
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(160, 160, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq6.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq7
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(310, 160, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq7.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq8
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(460, 160, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq8.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq9
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(10, 310, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq9.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq10
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(160, 310, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq10.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq11
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(310, 310, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq11.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq12
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(460, 310, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq12.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq13
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(10, 460, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq13.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq14
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(160, 460, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq14.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq15
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(310, 460, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq15.color;
  ctx.fill();

  //sq16
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(460, 460, 150, 150);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = sq16.color;
  ctx.fill();
}

window.setInterval(draw, 100) // repeat game loop function forever, 10 times per second(that value is measured in ms)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="620" height="620" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d"></canvas>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where you need to refer to the `number` of the `square`, let alone its properties.

Comment: @notacouch in the for/in loop inside the movement function - does that help?

Comment: But there is no `for` loop. There's something that's commented out, but it's not clear what's intended. Instead of `board` being a reference to just `full` values, why not assign them to the `square` objects themselves?

Comment: @notacouch I am talking about the segment that is commented out. I need the numbers of the `square`s in order to do mathematical operations with them

Comment: Right. Instead of `board = [ sq1.full, ...]` why not `board = [ sq1, sq2, ...]`?

Comment: @notacouch I could try that… I don't know how that would help me in the end, though, since I do need the values in the `.full` properties. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: You would access them via `board[0].full` (switch up `0` for the appropriate index) or in the loop's case... `sq_num.full`